# Rails: Filter by comparing between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, match, filtering

I confused about matching between two models. I have researched on stackoverflow and google until 2 days but no way...
There is more questions and answer about matching and filtering but it is about one way searching, listing. May be I couldn’t understand I’m not sure.
For example:
I have contents and users in my app.
I shared contents and I don’t want to make visible, likeable for all users.
Users should see who;

- Bigger than 18 years old and less than 70.
- must live at England and
  London city. (It can be changeable)
- they must have a drive license
- gender: man bla bla etc.

My first idea was create profile for users and take information from them.
Also create profile filter for `Content` model and fill the form like belov.

But problem is at final step;
“How i compare them for only users can see and like who has true attributes same as `Content` filter attributes.

Models;

`User` and `Content`

`Profile` belongs_to `user`

`Contentfilter` belongs_to `Content`

Than;
Show contens if current_user profile attributes same as Content filter.

Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to understand your schema and relations. It would be helpful if you could post your User, Content, and Profile models and the rest of the relevant code.

Comment: Does the content need to match all or some or the profile filters?

Comment: Yes. May be content will be available for all genders or all countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean any matching content but I'm providing a solution for both ALL or ANY matching profile filters.

Here's one quick solution on how you can achieve what you want.

Given the following models:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile, as: :profilable

  def all_matching_content
    profile: Profile.where(
      "? >= age", profile.age).
      where(
        gender: profile.gender,
        city: profile.city,
        license: profile.license).
      where(profilable_type: "Content"))
  end

  def any_matching_content
    Content.where(
      profile: Profile.where("? >= age", profile.age).
        or(Profile.where(gender: profile.gender)).
        or(Profile.where(city: profile.city)).
        or(Profile.where(license: profile.license)).
      where(profilable_type: "Content"))
    end
  end
end

# app/models/profile.rb
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profilable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end

# app/models/content.rb
class Content < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile, as: :profilable
end
```

And the following migrations:

```
# db/migrate/20181114004031_create_users.rb
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# db/migrate/20181114004134_create_profiles.rb
class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.references :profilable, polymorphic: true, null: true
      t.boolean :license, index: true
      t.string :city, index: true
      t.string :gender, index: true
      t.integer :age, index: true
      t.timestamps
      t.index [:license, :city, :gender, :age], name: "profile_composite_index"
    end
  end
end

# db/migrate/20181114004307_create_contents.rb
class CreateContents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :contents do |t|
      t.string :title, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And the following seeds:

```
# db/seeds.rb
User.create!(
  name: "John",
  profile: Profile.create!(
    license: true,
    city: "London",
    gender: "Male",
    age: 19
  )
)

User.create!(
  name: "Jane",
  profile: Profile.create!(
    license: false,
    city: "London",
    gender: "Female",
    age: 17
  )
)

User.create!(
  name: "Rose",
  profile: Profile.create!(
    license: true,
    city: "Edinburgh",
    gender: "Female",
    age: 21
  )
)

User.create!(
  name: "Hans",
  profile: Profile.create!(
    license: true,
    city: "Berlin",
    gender: "Male",
    age: 24
  )
)

Content.create!(
  title: "London introduces new tax",
  profile: Profile.create!(
    city: "London"
  )
)

Content.create!(
  title: "New license requirements in Berlin",
  profile: Profile.create!(
    city: "Berlin",
    license: true
  )
)

Content.create!(
  title: "Women should get new immunization",
  profile: Profile.create!(
    gender: "Female"
  )
)

Content.create!(
  title: "Adults only expo opens Wednesday",
  profile: Profile.create!(
    age: 18
  )
)
```

You'll be able to do the following:

```
> john = User.find_by(name: "John")
> john.all_matching_content
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

> john.any_matching_content.map(&:title)
=> ["London introduces new tax", "New license requirements in Berlin", "Adults only expo opens Wednesday"]

> jane = User.find_by(name: "Jane")
> jane.any_matching_content.map(&:title)
=> ["London introduces new tax", "Women should get new immunization"]

> rose = User.find_by(name: "Rose")
> rose.any_matching_content.map(&:title)
=> ["New license requirements in Berlin", "Women should get new immunization", "Adults only expo opens Wednesday"]

> hans = User.find_by(name: "Hans")
> hans.any_matching_content.map(&:title)
=> ["New license requirements in Berlin", "Adults only expo opens Wednesday"]
```

The solution works by sharing a polymorphic `Profile` model with `User` and `Content`. It then matches `Content` with the `User` instance by passing the user's `Profile` attributes to a query for matching profiles that belong to `Content` types.

Note that the `#all_matching_content` method requires that all profile attributes match, basically it means all conditons in the query are "AND"ed. The `#any_matching_content` method uses "OR" conditions instead.

I have uploaded a quick project to GitHub with this example already coded:

https://github.com/JurgenJocubeit/so-53289847

Comment: Thanks Jurgen! I will try and comment the result in there. only question beafore start, if we are making `profilable` in polymorphic, why you permitting params direct under content params? shouldn't be like `...(:content).(:title,profile_attirbutes: [:gender, :city, :etc] `?

Comment: Yes that's correct, if you want to pass nested attributes through params to the controller, you will need to add them as permitted params. The attrs you saw were artifacts from scaffolding the app out before I created a polymorphic Profile model. The controllers weren't necessary to show example worked because I used a seed file to add data to the database, and the console to query it. I've updated the github project to show the changes necessary in the controllers and in the models. The forms also need updating to include fields_for, this is something I haven't done. I can help if you want.

Comment: Thanks Jurgen. You have spent more time for my question. I will try to make it as way that you said. I know that can contact you if i couldn't achieve it. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm feeling generous today! I've updated the repo to include views, updated routes, and added delegates for profile in the User model. It demonstrates how you can read the profile values directly from the user instance, rather than having to go through the profile. The content model shows the traditional way of not using a delegate. All the views work including displaying and updating records. Just clone the latest version and run rails server and go to root url at localhost:3000.

Comment: I added a seed and the #all_matching_content list to the users show view to demonstrate how you can restrict content matching to all matching profile attributes instead of any matching attribute. Hope this helps you. If you find this example answers your question, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Hi jurgen, It is exactly this answer is what i need. Your answer will be marked as "accepted" I have just litle bit question but big important; ` what if content creator want to filter by age as " between 18 and 55 years old OR all ages" ? `
do you have any idea?

Comment: @mihraçcerrahoğlu I've added (to the github project) minimum and maximum age fields to the profile with scopes for restricting content returned. In order to remove age restrictions and allow any age, simply do not fill the age fields in the profile so they remain NULL in the database for that content. If you have any other questions please feel free to contact me on https://www.linkedin.com/in/jurgenjocubeit, or raise an issue at https://github.com/JurgenJocubeit/so-53289847/issues. I'm happy to help any time.